# Is it possible to append to multi-valued attributes in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to append to the list of values in a multi-valued attribute in an Amazon DynamoDB table? I am not quite able to figure it out using the put request. I would like to avoid the read, update, write logic if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to *String and Number Sets* as outlined in [Amazon DynamoDB Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes), this is possible in [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) by means of the [UpdateItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_UpdateItem.html) operation indeed:

> **ADD—** Only use the add action for numbers or if the target attribute is a set (including string sets). ADD does not work if the
>   target attribute is a single string value. The specified value is
>   added to a numeric value (incrementing or decrementing the existing
>   numeric value) **or added as an additional value in a string set. If a
>   set of values is specified, the values are added to the existing set.**
>   For example if the original set is [1,2] and supplied value is [3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_UpdateItem.html),
>   then after the add operation the set is [1,2,3], not [4,5]. [...]
>   *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: The link to the data types page at the time of writing is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes