# How can I add data to a multivalued attribute in DynamoDB using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

In my table, suppose I store some data like this :

```
Item(Table('test'), data={'id': '123', 'content': 'test', 'list': set([1,2,3,4])}).save()
```

This has a multivalued atribute 'list'. I want to search the table for id=123, and if it exists, update the 'list' attribute, by appending another list to it, say [5,6]

Some searching around led me to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603840/is-it-possible-to-append-to-multi-valued-attributes-in-dynamodb), which points to the UpdateItem operation, however I cannot find an example of how to use the ADD action.

Could anyone provide an example of how I could do this? I am a beginner to both python and DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
table = Table('users')

item = table.get_item(id=123)
for i in #your_list_to_append#:
    item['list'].append(i)
item.save(overwrite=True)
```